# How to Make delete confirmation modal using PHP

Tags: php, database, modal-dialog

When I click the delete button I want to make a confirmation on a Bootstrap modal, before the user can delete it. The problem is that i don't know how to passed the $muestra['id'] from the data table to my modal.

```
<?php
$busqueda=$conn->query("select * from productos");
$arrDatos=$busqueda->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($arrDatos as $muestra) {
        echo "<tr>
                <td>" . $muestra['id'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $muestra['nombre'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $muestra['unidades'] . "</td>

                <td>
                <a href='del.php?id=".$muestra['id']."' class='btn btn-danger' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#deleteModal'>   
                <ion-icon name='trash-outline'></ion-icon>
                </a>
                </td>
        </tr>
        
        <!-- Modal -->
      <div class='modal fade' id='deleteModal' tabindex='-1' aria-labelledby='deleteModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
        <div class='modal-dialog'>
          <div class='modal-content'>
            <div class='modal-header'>
              <h1 class='modal-title fs-5' id='deleteModalLabel'>¿Estás seguro de que quieres borrar el elemento?</h1>
              <button type='button' class='btn-close' data-bs-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'></button>
            </div>
            <div class='modal-body'>
            ¿Estás seguro de que quieres borrar el elemento?
            </div>
            <div class='modal-footer'>
              <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary' data-bs-dismiss='modal'>No</button>
              <a href='del.php?id=".$muestra['id']."' class='btn btn-danger'>Sí</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Modal -->
      ";
        }
?>
</table>
```

I've tried many things, I know it's a simple problem, I've searched in old answers, but I'm new to coding and I can't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There will be need of some JS since that is done on the browser side. Using JS you get the id attribute of the modal when the button is click and do your logic.